# AWS: InvalidSignature exception while adding record

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cli, amazon-kinesis

InvalidSignatureException occurs when trying to add user record using Kinesis Producer library.
AWS_JAVA_SDK_VERSION=1.10.26
AWS_KINESIS_PRODUCER_VERSION=0.10.1

**ERROR**:

PutRecords failed: {"__type":"InvalidSignatureException","message":"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method.

**SCALA KINESIS PRODUCER CODE**

```
private val configuration: KinesisProducerConfiguration = new KinesisProducerConfiguration
  val credentialsProvider: AWSCredentialsProvider = AwsUtil.getAwsCredentials(config.awsAccessKey, config.awsSecretKey)
  configuration.setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
  configuration.setRecordMaxBufferedTime(config.timeLimit)
  configuration.setAggregationMaxCount(1)
  configuration.setRegion(config.streamRegion)
  configuration.setMetricsLevel("none")
  private val kinesisProducer = new KinesisProducer(configuration)
  kinesisProducer.addUserRecord(streamName, key, eventBytes)`
```

The above code is not working. But its possible for me to add records to kinesis stream through aws cli from terminal and KinesisClient in code which is specified below.

```
private def createKinesisClient = {
    val accessKey = config.awsAccessKey
    val secretKey = config.awsSecretKey
    val credentialsProvider: AWSCredentialsProvider = AwsUtil.getAwsCredentials(accessKey, secretKey)
    val client = new AmazonKinesisClient(credentialsProvider)

    client.setEndpoint(config.streamEndpoint)
    client
  }
```

Comment: Did you check the your scala code is getting the Config object right? In general is it better to use EC2 roles and not provide explicit credentials even in configuration.

Comment: Shall you resort to writing you own request, I released a library to hep out with that: https://github.com/ticofab/aws-request-signer . Good luck!

Comment: Thanks guys. Finally the issue is fixed once updating the aws-sdk and kinesis-library to higher version.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because your VM/PC/Server clock might by skewed.

If you're running ubuntu, try updating your system time:

`sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com`

If you are using `docker-machine` on Mac, you can resolve with this command:

`docker-machine ssh default 'sudo ntpclient -s -h pool.ntp.org'`